# Replace placeholders in dom element

Tags: javascript

Given a dome element like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        {{placeholder|value1}}
    </ul>
    <a href="{{placeholder|value2}}">{{placeholder|value3}}</a>
</div>
```

and a json string containing the values:

```
var placeholder = {"values": {"value1" : "<li>hello</li>", "value2" : "#", "value3": "hello again"}}
```

what would be the correct way to replace the values in the dom element in a generalised way i.e. the example above is only for illustration and the placeholder|value can appear anywhere in the element.

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RPkY/

Comment: This is a very broad question. What approaches have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: My first approach get it as a string, replace the values and the convert back to dom element.  Dont think this is a good approach

Comment: And these placeholders can appear anywhere, in any attribute, element content etc ?

Comment: @adeneo yes they can be attribute values, content etc.  anything

Comment: Then stick with strings and regex ?

Comment: This is such an abstract question it's hard to avoid POV, and even so I can't imagine there being one definite solution. Maybe this is a question best fielded on Ember.js's forums regarding why they're developing HTMLbars vs Handlebars — even if you don't intend to use any of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I'd drop in some code to recursively iterate through all DOM nodes:

- If it's an Element, then iterate through its Attributes and replace placeholders, then recurse
- If it's a Text node, replace placeholders in its contents

Buuuuut... in this case you may just be better off nuking it with a regex:

```
output = input.replace(/\{\{placeholder\|(.*?)\}\}/g,function(_,k) {
     return placeholder[k] || _;
});
```

In this particular case, it's okay to parse HTML with regex because... well, the regex itself has nothing to do with HTML and does not affect the underlying HTML in any way.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8RPkY/2/

Comment: +1 for explaining the correct way of doing it, then why regex is OK in this case.