# Search For And Replace Placeholders in DOM Without innerHTML (and removing listeners)

Tags: javascript, html

I have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030826/replace-placeholders-in-dom-element), and have determined this question is different.

I am trying to find an elegant way to be able to comb through a DOM and replace instances of a particular string, WITHOUT calling innerHTML.

The reason why I'd like to avoid doing this is because doing so seems to strip all elements of their event listeners, which is catastrophic to the functionality of a webpage in many cases.

This is what I am currently using and, like I said, it's removing all listeners:

```
function placeholderReplacement(k,v){
let regex = new RegExp(k,"g");
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll(regex, v);
}
```

And I am calling this function like so:

```
placeholderReplacement('{placeholder1}', 'replacementValue1');
```

Note: Placeholders may appear anywhere in the DOM, it's not strictly limited to one type of element or section.

Is there any way I can accomplish this without calling innerHTML and stripping all existing eventListeners?

Comment: `.textContent` or `.innerText` if it's between tags. ex. `<tag>`TEXT`</tag>`. Post an example of what you are targeting in HTML.

Comment: Assigning to `innerHTML` shouldn't remove listeners as long as you only do this to leaf elements. If you do it to a container, all the contents will be reparsed from scratch.

Comment: @zer00ne it could be literally anywhere in the DOM, visible or not

Comment: @Barmar I need a way to scan through the entire body and replace as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventlisteners should not be removed if you target the right element, not its ancestors.

you could create a node iterator to find the textnodes and do your replacement directly on them, this wont touch eventlisteners

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li')].forEach(li => li.addEventListener('click', () => li.innerText+= " CLICK"));


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const search      = "boring";
    const replacement = "awesome";
    
    const textIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
      document.body,
      NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
    );
    let textNode;
    while ((textNode = textIterator.nextNode())) {
      textNode.data = textNode.data.replaceAll( search, replacement);     
    }

    const elemIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
      document.body,
      NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT
    );
    let elemNode;
    while ((elemNode = elemIterator.nextNode())) {
      [...elemNode.attributes].forEach((attr) => {
        elemNode.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value.replace(search, replacement)); 

      });
    }
});
```

```css
ul.boring {
  background-color: beige;
}

ul.awesome {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

#content.boring {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#content.awesome {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="boring">
  <p>these items are clickable</p>
  <ul class="list boring">
    <li>this list is boring</li>
    <li>boring things are very boring</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<button>Replace now</button>
```

beware, this will also replace the text inside `<style>` tags etc. which may not be desirable.

pass a function as a third argument to `createNodeIterator` to filter away unwanted tags.

[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator)

**EDIT:** I've added some code to replace within attributes as well.

This should work for most cases, but it wont replace text in comments. This would be an easy addition using `NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT` for the iterator. I'm sure you can add it if needed.

Replacement in TagNames is impossible without creating new elements. If you need this as well, you'll have to keep track of the eventlisteners when they get added and then re-add them to the new elements.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a textnode, it can be literally anywhere in the body

Comment: All text in HTML is within a text node, except things like tagnames and attributes. 

We can do replacement on attributes, but not tagnames as that requires creating a new tag and losing the eventlisteners. 

I'll add replacement to attributes to my answer at least.

Comment: I'm looking for an elegant way to find and replace placeholders that can be anywhere in the DOM, they can be located in attribute values, paragraphs, headings, input values, etc

Comment: I ran this and got `Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<' is not a valid attribute name.`

Comment: Did you get this error from running the snippet, or when running it on your own html-code? What browser are you using?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the HTML you're working with